# time in array - how to convert to timestamp?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array with time in PHP:

```
[time] => Array ( 
    [year] => 2007 
    [month] => 1 
    [day] => 2 
    [hour] => 1 
    [minute] => 1 )
)
```

i must save this in MySQL. in MySQL i have format

```
2007-01-02 01:01
```

how is the best method for modify array with time to timestamp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d", $arr['time']['year'], $arr['time']['month'], $arr['time']['day'], $arr['time']['hour'], $arr['time']['minute']);
```